# Read a file in specific format into ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, filereader

I have file with this specific format:

```
0  
2 4   
0 1 A  
0 5 B  
1 1 A  
1 3 B  
2 6 A  
2 4 B  
3 6 A  
3 4 B  
4 6 A  
4 4 B  
5 1 A  
5 5 B  
6 6 A  
6 2 B
```

- line 1 = start state
- line 2 = accept state
- line 3 - n = transition table
- 1st row = state in
- 2nd row = state out
- A,B = symbol

How can my `FileReader` in Java read these file into 5 different `ArrayList`s (start state, final state, state in, state out and symbol)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Scanner](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class to read the file ([nextLine() is highly recommended](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29)). Since you know the positions of the items you need, you can then use the [split](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method to parse the input string in what ever ArrayList you like.

Comment: Why not a simple `BufferedReader`?

Comment: can you explain  a little bit more? i'm new in java

Comment: @thejh: I do not understand what do you mean exactly. 
@gin: You know that the first 2 lines of the file are the start state and the acceptance state. Also, you know that from lines 3 to n, you need to split the lines into rows. So basically, do a while loop with a counter, and depending on the value of the counter, you know on which line you are working, thus you can fill the arraylists accordingly. Please take a look at the links I have provided to get a better understanding of how you can implement such system.

Comment: hhmm,. so i must make a while loop read the line which is for each line the while loop send the content of these line to different arraylist?

Comment: Yes. Read the lines and split them if necessary. Since all of the data has a fixed position, you should be able to put the right data in the right arraylist.

Answer (score 3):

It's best to use a [Scanner](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) here:

```
static class State {
    int in;
    int out;
    String symbol;

    State(int in, int out, String symbol) {
        this.in = in;
        this.out = out;
        this.symbol = symbol;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return in + " " + out + " " + symbol;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));

    int startState = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
    List<Integer> acceptStates = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    List<State> states = new LinkedList<State>();

    Scanner st = new Scanner(s.nextLine());
    while (st.hasNextInt())
        acceptStates.add(st.nextInt());

    while (s.hasNextInt())
        states.add(new State(s.nextInt(), s.nextInt(), s.next()));

    System.out.println(startState);
    System.out.println(acceptStates);
    System.out.println(states);

    // logic...
}
```

Comment: I think that the OP wants the second line to become a list of accept states.

Comment: is it have the same code if i use 'in' and 'out' in string rather than int?

Comment: Almost, use next() instead of nextInt() then.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [StringTokenizer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html), use `ArrayList`s to build up your lists.

Comment: From its javadoc: *StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code*.